# What is the connection between Euler's Formula and solving differences of powers?

Tags: trigonometry

Euler's formula is the following: $e^{ix} = \cos(x) + i\sin(x)$

By difference of powers, I mean $a^n - b^n = 0$ specifically $x^n - 1 = 0$

When I [calculate](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Power%5Bx%2C3%5D-1%20%3D%200) $x^3 - 1 = 0$ I get $x = (1, \frac{-1}{2} +\frac{i \sqrt3}{2},\frac{-1}{2} -\frac{i \sqrt3}{2})$ This is similar to cos and sin relating to these numbers. Specifically $-\frac{1}{2} + \frac{i\sqrt{3}}{2} = \cos(\frac23\pi) + i\sin(\frac23\pi) = e^{\frac23\pi i}$. My question is "Why do these relate?"

Comment: Because $(e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i})^3 =e^{3\frac{2\pi}{3}i}=e^{2\pi i}=1$. So $x=e^{\frac{2\pi}{3}i}$ solves $x^3-1=0$.

Comment: Are you asking why euler's formula holds? Because surely if euler's formula holds, you can rewrite something like $x^3 -1 = 0$ as $x^3 = 1 \implies x^3 = \cos(2\pi k) + i \sin (2\pi k) = e^{i(2\pi k)}$ which means 
$$x = e^{i\left(\frac{2\pi k}{3}\right)}$$
which gives you all your solutions

Comment: You can try searching about **Roots of unity** since that is the name of what you are trying to find.

Comment: @Sam I actually took the question to be about essentially what your comment explains. So maybe it can be written as an answer, or see if OP clarifies.

Answer (score 1):

Think about the geometry of the complex plane.

To multiply two complex numbers, you multiply the lengths and add the angles. That tells you that the solutions to
$$
x^n -1
$$
form a regular $n$-gon on the unit circle at angles $2k\pi/n$. The exponentiation rule tells you those points are the points $e^{2k\pi i/n}$.
You can see the real and imaginary parts of those points in Euler's formula.

As @soupless suggests, look up [roots of unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity).

Answer (score 1):

On the request of @aschepler, I'm turning my comment into an answer with a bit of extra detail.

From what I understand, either the question is asking: why is $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$? Or it's asking: Given that $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$, why are the solutions of $x^n - 1 = 0$ of the form $e^{i\left(\frac{2\pi k}{n}\right)}$. I'll answer both.

Starting with the first question. Consider the function
$$f(\theta) = \frac{\cos\theta + i\sin\theta}{e^{i\theta}} = \left(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta\right)e^{-i\theta}$$
We know immediately that $f(0) = 1$.
We can also tell that
$$f'(\theta) = (-\sin \theta + i\cos \theta)e^{-i\theta} + (-i\cos \theta + \sin \theta)e^{-i\theta} = 0$$
Since $f'(\theta) = 0$ everywhere, $f(\theta)$ must be constant. Since $f(0) = 1$, $f(\theta) = 1$. So
$$\left(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta\right)e^{-i\theta} = 1 \\
\implies \cos \theta + i \sin \theta = e^{i\theta}$$

Now the next question. Notice that $1 = \cos(2\pi k) + i\sin(2\pi k) = e^{i(2\pi k)}$ for every integer $k$. In the equation $x^n = 1$, we can subtitute this result to get:
$$x^n = e^{i(2\pi k)}$$
Taking the $n$th root on both sides gives us the desired result:
$$x = e^{i\left(\frac{2 \pi k}{n}\right)}$$